# What non-standard ports are safe to use?

Tags: apache

I'm using a non-standard port for the administrator controls and I'm wondering if theres any particular port I should use or is it safe to just use any port that doesn't have any script assigned to it?

Answer (score 10):

Long story short anything above 1024 is "safe" if I am understanding your definition of safe.  Although, I can certainly check all ports on your box.

My impression (please correct if I am wrong) but most people scanning boxes usually do not go above 1024 on a broad range scan.  They may check all ports if it is a box of particular interest to them.

Perhaps explain your situation a bit more and what the desired end result is and we can formulate a plan for you.

Comment: If I want to run a virtual host on another port using Apache, what ports would be safe?

Comment: "safe" is a relative term, can you give a bit more context?

Comment: Yeah, true. I was just trying to clarify the question as I had the same question. I think you should list the chrome allowed ports in your answer, as that was the issue I was having -- chrome doesn't allow certain ports without starting it differently. [link](http://superuser.com/questions/188058/which-ports-are-considered-unsafe-on-chrome) If you use one of those ports, you'll get the error `net::ERR_UNSAFE_PORT` on chrome

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer, JVE is right. There are many ports above 1024 that don't work.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a list of commonly used port numbers: http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers
I would say to avoid the ones on this list.

Comment: is there a list of ranges of ports that are safe? Like 10 to 300 or whatever for example?

Comment: Most ports are safe. At this writing, any port in the 5000s, 7000s and 9000s is safe. Here's a better list of unsafe ports: https://superuser.com/questions/188058/which-ports-are-considered-unsafe-on-chrome